# Bladed spokes on drive side, regular on other side

Tags: wheels, spokes

Yesterday, I checked out a Cannondale Synapse with Mavic Aksium wheels. One strange detail caught my eye - the rear wheel had bladed spokes on the drive side, and regular, cylindrical spokes on the non-drive side.

Is this a feature or did the shopkeeper mess around with the wheels?

Comment: It would be ridiculous to "mess around" with a wheel to produce a spoke setup that didn't come from the factory.  The wheel itself may have been swapped, but not the spokes.

Comment: Is this a new bike or a used model they are selling?

Comment: @mikes it's a brand new bike.

Answer (score 1):

Your first, and possibly best, place to start researching is the [Cannondale website](https://www.cannondale.com/en/USA/Products/ProductCategory.aspx?nid=71fb0b57-8db4-4549-b9eb-b50f7cfd4ed0).  It appears that 2 models of the Synapse, the [Synapse Carbon Disc Ultegra](https://www.cannondale.com/en/USA/Bike/ProductDetail?Id=303c39e8-761a-493d-9b08-2e6d02f0dbf6&parentid=undefined) and [Synapse Carbon Disc Ultegra DI2](https://www.cannondale.com/en/USA/Bike/ProductDetail?Id=6a37625d-4569-467f-852a-5391e5b4e24d&parentid=undefined) come standard with Mavic Aksium Disc wheels.  You could then refer to the [Mavic website](https://shop.mavic.com/en-ca/aksium-disc-rr0989.html#1028=3283) to get the specs on those.

Comment: the bike was a rim brake one, not disk.

Comment: Looking on Mavic's own website, they do ship it with round spokes on rear non-drive side and bladed on drive side - https://shop.mavic.com/en-int/aksium-rr0988.html#1028=3283. Navigate to specifications > Spokes. This is really strange to me and I've personally never seen something like this. I'm really interested in understanding the reason for this mixture of spokes.

Comment: Do bladed spokes provide any benefit other than reduced drag?

Comment: @HarshilSharma Maybe, the reason is just "because it sells". But if anyone knew a better reason, I'd also be very interested to read about it...

Comment: The real explanation is likely under NDA, but I can come with three plausible ones: a) Cost/benefit: flat spokes are more expensive than round, so on a budget wheelset it makes sense to put those only on the side that is more in the wind. b) Marketing: asymmetric spokes at rear look technical and this is a cheap way to get the effect and possibly make people think of option a. c) Logistics: Mavic had lots of mismatched spokes in inventory when the first production run was made, and since the wheels sold well, they kept the spec

Comment: It lowers the price for one wheel-set say by 5-10€. Multiply that by the number of sets produced it will be substantial.